# Why regex with lookaheads doesn't match?

Tags: php, regex

I need (in PHP) to split a sententse by the word that cannot be the first or the last one in the sentence. Say the word is "pression" and here is my regex

```
/^.+?(?=[\s\.\,\:\;])pression(?=[\s\.\,\:\;]).+$/i
```

Live here: https://regex101.com/r/CHAhKj/1/

First, it doesn't match.
Next, I think - it is at all possible to split that way? I tryed simplified example

```
print_r(preg_split('/^.+pizza.+$/', 'my pizza is cool'));
```

live here http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/10b674900fc1ef44ec79bfaf80e83fe1f4248d02

and it prints an array of 2 empty strings, when I expect
`['my ', ' is cool']`

Comment: `print_r(explode('pizza', 'my pizza is cool'));` works just fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I need (in PHP) to split a sentence by the word that cannot be the first or the last one in the sentence

You may use this regex:

```sh
(?<=[^\s.?]\h)pression(?=\h[^\s.?])
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/CHAhKj/3)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?<=[^\s.?]\h)`: Lookbehind to assert that ahead of current position we have a space and a character that not a whitespace, not a dot and not a `?`.
- `pression`: Match word `pression`
- `(?=\h[^\s.?])`: Lookahead to assert that before current position we have a space and a character that not a whitespace, not a dot and not a `?`

Comment: Great, thank you! I've just removed ";" since it's a normal symbol inside a sentence.

Answer (score 1):

First, `^.+?(?=[\s\.\,\:\;])pression(?=[\s\.\,\:\;]).+$` can't match any string at all because the `(?=[\s\.\,\:\;])p` part requires `p` to be also either a whitespace char, or a `.`, `,`, `:` or `;`, which invalidates the whole match at once.

Second, `^.+pizza.+$` pattern does not ensure the `pizza` matched is not the first or last word in a sentence as `.` matches whitespace, too. It does not return anything meaningful, because `preg_split` uses the match to break string into chunks, and the two empty values are 1) start of string and 2) empty string positions.

That said, all you need is:

```php
preg_match('~^(.*?\w\W+)pression(\W+\w.*)$~is', $text, $m)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PnNEVJ/1/). Details:

- `^` - start of string
- `(.*?\w\W+)` - Capturing group 1: any zero or more chars, as few as possible, then a word char and then one or more non-word chars
- `pression` - a word
- `(\W+\w.*)`  - Capturing group 2: one or more non-word chars, a word char, and then any zero or more chars as many as possible
- `$` - end of string.

`s` makes the `.` match across lines and `i` flag makes the pattern match in a case insensitive way.

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/ICr63):

```php
$text = "You can use any regular expression pression inside the lookahead ";
if (preg_match('~^(.*?\w\W+)pression(\W+\w.*)$~is', $text, $m)) {
    echo $m[1] . " << | >> " . $m[2];
}
// => You can use any regular expression  << | >>  inside the lookahead
```